# LoginUser_Authenticate and LoggingIn events won't fire

Tags: c#, asp.net, login-control

I'm currently developing a website that uses FormAuthentication to log in a user against an ActiveDirectory Domain. I need to create a login form to handle the user credentials since they must be able to log into multiple domains regardless of the local user pc domain.

I figured I would use the Login WebControl. My problem is that neither Authenticate nor LoggingIn events fire when the user logs in.

Here is my aspx login page:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Logon.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebSite1.Logon1" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors.v11.2, Version=11.2.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" Namespace="DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors" TagPrefix="dx" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <p>
        Por favor ingrese usuario y contraseña.
    </p>
    <asp:Login ID="LoginUser" runat="server"
        RenderOuterTable="false" RememberMeSet="true" FailureText="El usuario/contraseña no es correcto, por favor intente nuevamente"
        OnAuthenticate="LoginUser_Authenticate" OnLoggingIn="LoginUser_LoggingIn">
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <span class="failureNotification">
                <asp:Literal ID="FailureText" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
            </span>
            <dx:ASPxValidationSummary ID="LoginUserValidationSummary" runat="server" CssClass="failureNotification" ValidationGroup="LoginUserValidationGroup">
            </dx:ASPxValidationSummary>
            <div class="accountInfo">
                <fieldset class="login">
                    <legend>Información de cuenta</legend>
                    <p>
                        <dx:ASPxLabel ID="DomainLabel" runat="server" Text="Dominio:" AssociatedControlID="Domain">
                        </dx:ASPxLabel>
                        <dx:ASPxComboBox ID="Domain" runat="server" Width="250px">
                        </dx:ASPxComboBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="DomainRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Domain"
                            CssClass="failureNotification" ErrorMessage="El dominio es requerido." ToolTip="El dominio es requerido."
                            ValidationGroup="LoginUserValidationGroup">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <dx:ASPxLabel ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" Text="Usuario:" AssociatedControlID="UserName">
                        </dx:ASPxLabel>
                        <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" CssClass="textEntry" Width="250px">
                        </dx:ASPxTextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName"
                            CssClass="failureNotification" ErrorMessage="El nombre de usuario es requerido." ToolTip="El nombre de usuario es requerido."
                            ValidationGroup="LoginUserValidationGroup">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <dx:ASPxLabel ID="PasswordLabel" runat="server" Text="Contraseña:" AssociatedControlID="Password">
                        </dx:ASPxLabel>
                        <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="Password" runat="server" CssClass="passwordEntry" Width="250px" Password="True">
                        </dx:ASPxTextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PasswordRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Password"
                            CssClass="failureNotification" ErrorMessage="La contraseña es requerida." ToolTip="La contraseña es requerida."
                            ValidationGroup="LoginUserValidationGroup">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <dx:ASPxCheckBox ID="RememberMe" runat="server">
                        </dx:ASPxCheckBox>
                        <dx:ASPxLabel ID="RememberMeLabel" runat="server" Text="Mantener sesión iniciada" AssociatedControlID="chkRememberMe" CssClass="inline">
                        </dx:ASPxLabel>
                    </p>
                </fieldset>
                <dx:ASPxButton ID="LoginButton" runat="server" Text="Iniciar sesión" ValidationGroup="LoginUserValidationGroup">
                </dx:ASPxButton>
            </div>
        </LayoutTemplate>
    </asp:Login>
</asp:Content>
```

As you can see, `OnAuthenticate="LoginUser_Authenticate" OnLoggingIn="LoginUser_LoggingIn"` are set in the login control properties. I defined both methods on code behind and set breakpoints. The page is doing a postback since it gets refreshed, but the events never get called.

I've already checked for `AutoEventWireup="true"`, and web.config is configured to use this form for login:

`<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="logon.aspx" name="adAuthCookie" timeout="10" path="/">
 </forms>`

Can anyone suggest what to look for to find what might be wrong?

### EDIT:

As requested here is my code behind class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors;

namespace WebSite1
{
    public partial class Logon1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected ASPxComboBox Domain;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Domain = LoginUser.FindControl("Domain") as ASPxComboBox;
            Domain.Items.Clear();
            String allowedDomains = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AllowedDomains"];
            List<string> allowedDomainsList = allowedDomains.Split('|').ToList<string>();
            foreach (string allowedDomain in allowedDomainsList)
            {
                Domain.Items.Add(allowedDomain, allowedDomain);
            }
            Domain.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }

        protected void LoginUser_LoggingIn(object sender, LoginCancelEventArgs e)
        { 

        }

        protected void LoginUser_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

### Edit 2:

Changed `public partial class Login1 : System.Web.UI.Page` to `public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page`

And `CodeBehind="Logon.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebSite1.Logon1"` to `CodeBehind="Logon.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebSite1.Logon"`

No changes in behaviour so far.

### Edit 3:

I found this link [Customizing the Appearance of ASP.NET Login Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178339%28v=vs.100%29.ASPX) that explains that I need to catch the command event of my Login Button.
So I implemented this method:

```
protected void LoginButton_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.CommandName)
    {
        case "LogginIn":
            LoginUser_LoggingIn(sender, e);
            break;
    }
}
```

My problem now is that I don't know how to call the LogginIn event since `e` is a `CommandEventArgs` and I need a `LoginCancelEventArgs`.

Comment: Is the login control inside a `FORM`? I can't tell because you didn't post the markup for the `Master` page.

Comment: Icarus, `<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">` is defined in the Master page and there it is inside a Form tag. I can post the Site.Master code if you need it.

Comment: If you declared the methods as `protected` in your code behind, I can't think of anything else that may cause a problem.

Comment: They are declared as `protected`.

Comment: I'll try to remove the Master page inheritance and see what happens. Altough I doubt it would make a difference, otherwise all my other forms would have the same problem.

Comment: I see: CodeBehind="Logon.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebSite1.Logon1".  Can you make sure it's pointing to right class? May be you can share your login page's code behind.

Comment: @gbs It is pointing to the right class as you can see in my edit.

Comment: Actually it isn't. I've just noticed that my code behind class was defined as Logon1. Hadn't noticed that before.
What I don't get is how did Page_Load code worked.
I changed `public partial class Logon1 : System.Web.UI.Page` to `public partial class Logon : System.Web.UI.Page` but it still didn't fired the events.

Comment: How about start from scratch for troubleshooting...Add a new page and drag just the login control(no customization) and add the handlers for those two events i.e. A simple page with with just login control.

Comment: That actually works. Wich makes me think I might have a problem with the Log In button. 
Could it be missing some sort of command property to tell the Login Control the user wants to log in?

Comment: I found this link [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178339(v=vs.100).ASPX].

Comment: Ok you are using a dx button...may be that is doing something. Try adding CommandName="Login" to the button.

Comment: That did it.

Thanks for the tip :)

Comment: You don't have to add anything for Logging event other than the handler. It should be raised for you by Login Control.

Answer (score 0):

According to what you've written your public partial class name and your Inherits attribute still don't match.

```
Inherits="WebSite1.Logon"
```

but

```
public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
```

Shouldn't both be either Login or Logon?

Comment: Sorry, it was a Copy & Paste error. I copied it from a test form. It's Logon in both cases.